# How to acces a line in a file in O(1) by preprocessing the file?

Tags: c++, file

In C++, I would like to access a line in a file. The line holds a key, value pair. I don't have enough in program memory to store this in a map because the value size is too large.

I would like to store the positions of the keys in the file in a map. Then access their values when a query comes in. Is it possible to do this in O(1)? If so, what should I use in C++ i.e. fseek(),etc? Also, what needs to stored in terms of position of the key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to store the file positions against the keys. You can use [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and its [seekg();](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) member function to locate the line in the file.

Comment: No - unless the lines have constant width.

Comment: What do you want to do in O(1)? Searching a key/value pair or seeking file to read it?

Comment: Assuming your file is read-only and the position of your value never changes, store the `long offset` that points to the first character of your value (for `seek()`) and `long size` that indicates how long your value string is (for `read()`). There is no hard guarantee of O(1) constant time, as files can be fragmented over the disk and can be cached.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Seeking the file, but Marcus has already answered that. Thanks though.

Comment: @taoufik - Thanks. Makes sense.

Thanks to Galik as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fseek()` is simply the system call to move your read/write pointer in your file; the complexity of that is completely up to your OS and your file system, and of course your storage device (eg. on an SSD, `fseek(x)` will have a time that is invariant of the last and the new position, whilst on a tape drive, things will be depend on relative distances. Unless your OS starts caching file contents in RAM, which it will stop doing once you run out of free RAM).

Answer (score 3):

In lieu of rolling your own indexing of the file as you described, you might consider loading it into one of the many open source C/C++ databases out there, especially since your data is organized as key-value-pairs, presumably with small keys and large or arbitrary values.

One suggestion is Google's LevelDB, but there are several other great options as well, depending on your other criteria beyond performance.

http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/07/leveldb-fast-persistent-key-value-store.html

Most should be configurable for constant time access (or at least nearly enough to constant time for all practical purposes).